# Como chamo uma função em outra?

Tags: php

Eu estou tentando chamar essa função aqui

```
$bodyText = "The text you want to filter goes here.";

 function formatUrlsInText($text) {
 $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
 preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $text, $matches);

 $usedPatterns = array(); 
 foreach($matches[0] as $pattern){
    if(!array_key_exists($pattern, $usedPatterns)){
       $usedPatterns[$pattern]=true;

       // now try to catch last thing in text 
       $pattern2 = substr($pattern, -3);

       if($pattern2 == "gif" || $pattern2 == "peg" || $pattern2 == "jpg" || $pattern2                    == "png") {
         $text = str_replace($pattern, '<img src="'.$pattern.'">', $text); 
       } else {
          $text = str_replace($pattern, '<a href="'.$pattern.'">'.$pattern.'</a>',      $text);
       } 
       }
       }
      return $text; 
     }

    $format = formatUrlsInText($bodyText);

    echo $format;
```

para essa

```
<div class="video-page-desc">
<?php
if ($player_icons ['showTag'] == 1) {
  echo $this->htmlVideoDetails->description;
}
 ?>
</div>
```

A primeira função e para converte *url* em *text* para *url* clicável.
"notasse que no final da primeira função esta sendo convertida para `$bodyText = "";` que no primeiro caso `$bodyText = " ";` só esta nessa função para teste."

A segunda função e onde sai a descrição do site. "essa eu não sei muito o que dizer"

O objetivo e converte as *url* *text* da descrição para *url* clicáveis

Vocês poderiam dar alguma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar esta função da página seria simplesmente ter certeza que o arquivo que contém ela está incluído no arquivo que deseja utiliza-la e fazer assim:

```html
<div class="video-page-desc">
<?php
  if ($player_icons ['showTag'] == 1) {
    echo formatUrlsInText($this->htmlVideoDetails->description);
  }
?>
</div>
```

Mas você precisa ter certeza que o atributo `$this->htmlVideoDetails->description` retorna um *link*, porque esta ficando entendido que `description` seria a descrição do registro, verifique se existe um atributo *link*, *url* ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Vlw Rafael você é o cara